# try/catch holds for + if + switch statements, break; needed after if statement enclosed in for loop that contains switch, why?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, break

I'm kind of new to Java and I can't really understand `break;` that's needed after `if` statement in my code. If I don't add the last `break;` statement after `switch` is closed, I get multiple copies of songs that have same title just different time length.

However, if I add `break;`, I only get one copy of specified song inside user's music file. I'm trying to understand why is that happening. Is it because if I don't break away from `if` statement that holds the `switch` then the switch repeats it self?

```
try{
     Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        //looping through user requested file of music
        while (input.hasNextLine()){

            //reads new line in the file
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split("[,]");

            // loops through list of all songs
            for (int i = 0; i < allSongs.length; i++){

                String nameOfSong = tokens[1];

                if (allSongs[i].getTitle().equals(nameOfSong)){

                    String playlistTypeName = tokens[0];

                    switch (playlistTypeName){
                        case "playlist1":
                            playlist1.enqueue(allSongs[i]);
                            break;

                        case "playlist2":
                            playlist2.enqueue(allSongs[i]);
                            break;

                        case "playlist3":
                            playlist3.enqueue(allSongs[i]);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It means that the condition `allSongs[i].getTitle().equals(nameOfSong)` matches many entries in `allSongs`. Breaking the loop makes sure that you stop adding after the first match is found.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense :)

Comment: Awesome, it's very helpful, thank you tons.  I didn't know about map, learned something new :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a switch in a loop in a loop.
The `break` statements within the switch body "jump" out of the **switch** part.

But that code **still** sits in a loop (which sits in another loop).

Thus, the *outer* break affects how the "looping" takes place.

So, the real answer here is to step back and look at each of these things individually. And one good way to get there is by **not** putting so many things into a single method. Rather use a distinct method that does the "switch" handling by itself.

In other words: you put too much complexity into your code. And now you lost track of what is going on.

And to be more precise: in your case, you are using the *wrong* solution. Meaning: what you actually want to do is to **map** a string (like "playlist1" to a specific object. So instead of doing that *manually*, using a switch statement, you *could* use

```
Map<String, PlayList> playListsByName = new HashMap<>();
playListsByName.put("playlist1", playlist1);
...
```

And then your *switch* statement goes away, and instead you do something like:

```
 PlayList plist = playListsByName.get(yourToken);
 if (plist != null) {
    plist.enqueue(allSongs[i]);
 } else {
   ... error handling: invalid play list token
```

Comment: Got it, thank you, I do need to break that method to be more simple, I'm just trying to figure out how to pull out that switch statement and make it work without breaking all of it because its dependent on allSong[i]

Comment: Just a quick follow up question if I may. Would I do the Map<> for each playlist separately if I have 3 playlists?  I'm asking because I have 3 different play list queues, so I'm trying to figure out if map has to be done for each of those.

Comment: Would I add Map under the for loop?  (Sorry for so many questions just trying to wrap my mind around this)

Comment: @Niki You add on the smallest scope it fits in. If you need it in more than one place, you make it a field of your class for example. But even when it is just a "local" variable within that method - then you would put the code to initialize that map into its own method. Try to dissect your problem into many small pieces, and ideally, one method per piece!